# PCRE, regex not detecting subpattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the PCRE pattern:

```
$pattern = '/(.*)(\[(heading)\](.*)\[\/\3\])(.*)/Us'
```

and this text

$text ='Distilled water from a Millipore Milli-Q system (Billerica, MA, USA).
HPLC-grade methanol and acetonitrile purchased from J. T. Baker Phillipsburg, NJ, USA).
[heading]HEading test[/heading]
3-Aminofluoranthene purchased from Aldrich (Milwaukee, WI, USA).
1-Aminopyrene
1-palmitoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
caffeine
cytosine
formic acid (LC/MS grade)
nalidixic acid
theophylline
HPLC-grade leucine enkephalin purchased from Fluka (Milwaukee, WI, USA)
Amitriptyline hydrochloride
β-Asp-Leu
isoleucine
γ-Glu-Leu
hippuric acid
leucine
1-oleoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
phenylalanine
1-stearoyl-glycero-phosphocholine
tryptophan and tyrosine purchased from Sigma (St. Louis, MO, USA).
'

When I run:

```
preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

it doesn't capture the last subpattern, the '(.*)' at the end, and I don't understand why not. Any explanations?

(That is, it captures 'Distilled water from a Millipore Milli-Q system (Billerica, MA, USA).
HPLC-grade methanol and acetonitrile purchased from J. T. Baker Phillipsburg, NJ, USA).
[heading]HEading test[/heading]'

but not the last part of the string:

'
3-Aminofluoranthene purchased from Aldrich (Milwaukee, WI, USA).
1-Aminopyrene
1-palmitoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
caffeine
cytosine
formic acid (LC/MS grade)
nalidixic acid
theophylline
HPLC-grade leucine enkephalin purchased from Fluka (Milwaukee, WI, USA)
Amitriptyline hydrochloride
β-Asp-Leu
isoleucine
γ-Glu-Leu
hippuric acid
leucine
1-oleoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
phenylalanine
1-stearoyl-glycero-phosphocholine
tryptophan and tyrosine purchased from Sigma (St. Louis, MO, USA).'

which I want)

Comment: What exactly do you wan't to fetch from $text string ?

Comment: I could have any text of the form: "text1[heading]text2[/heading]text3[heading]text4[/heading]text5". Where the number of occurances of the heading tag can be 0 or more. And I want to catch the text parts, inside of and outside of the tags. (More generally the pattern should also be able to capture the name of the tag, which can be any name from a given list, but I simplified the pattern so that the only tag name being captured is heading to shorten the question since I didn't consider that part to be relevant for the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me when I remove the greediness inversion flag.

`$pattern = '/(.*)(\[(heading)\](.*)\[\/\3\])(.*)/s';`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Distilled water from a Millipore Milli-Q system (Billerica, MA, USA).
HPLC-grade methanol and acetonitrile purchased from J. T. Baker Phillipsburg, NJ, USA).
[heading]HEading test[/heading]
3-Aminofluoranthene purchased from Aldrich (Milwaukee, WI, USA).
1-Aminopyrene
1-palmitoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
caffeine
cytosine
formic acid (LC/MS grade)
nalidixic acid
theophylline
HPLC-grade leucine enkephalin purchased from Fluka (Milwaukee, WI, USA)
Amitriptyline hydrochloride
Î²-Asp-Leu
isoleucine
Î³-Glu-Leu
hippuric acid
leucine
1-oleoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
phenylalanine
1-stearoyl-glycero-phosphocholine
tryptophan and tyrosine purchased from Sigma (St. Louis, MO, USA).

                    [1] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Distilled water from a Millipore Milli-Q system (Billerica, MA, USA).
HPLC-grade methanol and acetonitrile purchased from J. T. Baker Phillipsburg, NJ, USA).

                    [1] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [heading]HEading test[/heading]
                    [1] => 160
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => heading
                    [1] => 161
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => HEading test
                    [1] => 169
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
3-Aminofluoranthene purchased from Aldrich (Milwaukee, WI, USA).
1-Aminopyrene
1-palmitoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
caffeine
cytosine
formic acid (LC/MS grade)
nalidixic acid
theophylline
HPLC-grade leucine enkephalin purchased from Fluka (Milwaukee, WI, USA)
Amitriptyline hydrochloride
Î²-Asp-Leu
isoleucine
Î³-Glu-Leu
hippuric acid
leucine
1-oleoyl-glycero-3-phosphocholine
phenylalanine
1-stearoyl-glycero-phosphocholine
tryptophan and tyrosine purchased from Sigma (St. Louis, MO, USA).

                    [1] => 191
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I agree.  I ran it through Regex buddy and it works. Group 5 does start with a "newline" character, so careful of that.

Comment: The `s` flag covers dots matching newlines, so I'm guessing you're talking about `trim()`ing the results. Good catch.

Comment: But I need the greediness inversion. I might sometimes have a text like: "bla[heading]blah[/heading]bladi[heading]bla[/heading]blah". And then I need to catch each tagged text and the texts outside of the heading tags.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single expression without making it extremely bloated. Please update the OP with an example that DOESN'T work with the `U`-less expression, and what data you expect returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the last (.*) with (.|\n)*

Comment: That screwed up other parts of the regex, and the 's' flag does that already.